# PDI Big Data Hadoop File Input from Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to run a kettle kjb which has a hadoop file input and hadoop file output step. All i am trying to do is to read from the hadoop file input and dump the results to a file on the same hdfs system. I am able to run the kjb successfully when i ran through spoon. I used pentaho 6.0 to run the kjb.

I am trying to run the same kjb from java. I added the following pentaho-big-data plugin maven dependency along with other required kettle dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
    <artifactId>pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
</dependency>
```

Apart from this, I also included this following suggested line of code to set the plugins folder before initializing the kettle environment.

String plugInDir = "target/pentaho-big-data-kettle-plugins-hdfs-7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar";

```
    StepPluginType.getInstance().getPluginFolders().add(new PluginFolder(plugInDir,false, true));
    KettleEnvironment.init();

    JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta(filename, null, null);
    Job job = initializeKettle(filename, jobMeta);
```

Inspite of doing all this, I am still getting the following missing plugins error while loading a transformation.

6:23:47.091 [main] ERROR c.r.t.k.RmsKettleExecuteTemplate - There were errors during kettle transformation execution.SampleKjb - org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
Unexpected error during transformation metadata load

Missing plugins found while loading a transformation

Step : HadoopFileInputPlugin
Step : HadoopFileOutputPlugin

```
at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.getTransMeta(JobEntryTrans.java:1205)
at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.trans.JobEntryTrans.execute(JobEntryTrans.java:648)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:716)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.access$000(Job.java:115)
at org.pentaho.di.job.Job$1.run(Job.java:835)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleMissingPluginsException: 
Missing plugins found while loading a transformation

Can someone please suggest on what maven dependencies do i need to use or is there anything else I need to set while running the job from java in order to get this working from java ?

Thanks